# Adobe Animate: Accessing a text field by forming name dynamically

Tags: flash, adobe

In my scene, I have rows and columns of text fields, which I have named based on the row and column ID (eg/ "r0c5").

How can I access this inside of a Movieclip by dynamically forming the textfield's name from integer variables for the row and column (eg/ Row 5, Column 6: *movieclip_name*.this['r' + 0 + 'c' + 0].text = ...; )

Comment: I have no idea why someone rated down my question.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right :)

```
movieclip_name[("r" + 5 + "c" + 6)].text = ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.